# How to conditional format a cell based on a date entered in an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I am setting up a Training Matrix spreadsheet, so I want a spreadsheet that highlights annual refresher training. Cells in column AO to be:

`GREEN` if today's date is within `330` days of the date in column AM
 `AMBER` if today's date is between `330 and 365` days of the date in column AM
 `RED` if today's date is greater than `365` of the date in column AM

and remain white if a date is entered in it.

*From Comment:*

> the dates in column AM would be in the past

Comment: So, what problem do you stuck with, when trying to do it?

Comment: @simoco the problem is I do not know where to start

Comment: Ok, I think this article could give you a good start: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx

Comment: @simoco thanks but trying to follow this and it doesnt seem to do want I want it to, the cells just stay white

Comment: @simoco I am trying formulas but I dont think I am getting them right for what I want, as nothing happens

Comment: Can you rephrase please `within a year 330 days of todays date` and `within 35 days of todays date plus a year`?

Comment: @simoco ok the training is required yearly, so if todays date is within 330 days of the date in column AO then cell AM goes GREEN

Comment: @simooco if todays date is between 330 and 364 days of the date in column AO then cell AM goes AMBER

Comment: @simoco then id todays date is 365+ days of date in column AO then cell AM goes RED

Comment: @simoco the dates in column AO would be in the past

Comment: I'm little confused, in question you asked how to highlight column AO, based on values on column AM, but in comments you say `then cell AM goes AMBER`..where is the truth?:)

Comment: @simoco sorry I am confusing myself and you, I have got the AM and AO the wrong way round in the comments

Comment: so, dates in column AM in the future?

Comment: the dates in column AM would be in the past and it is column AO that I want the cell to change colour

Comment: @simoco the dates in column AM would be in the past and it is column AO that I want the cell to change colou

Comment: @pnuts then AO cell would turn 'GREEN'

Comment: @pnuts is my question clear now?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Select entire column `AO`. **With selected range** go to *Conditional Formatting->New Rule...*

[image]

**Step 2.** Create new rule with *"Use a formula to determine wich cell to format..."*, enter a formula `=AND($AO1="",$AM1<>"",TODAY()-$AM1>365)` and choose **red** format (by pressing <kbd>Format</kbd> button). Press *OK*

[image]

**Step 3.** Select *New Rule*

[image]

**Step 4.** Enter formula for new rule `=AND($AO1="",$AM1<>"",TODAY()-$AM1>330,TODAY()-$AM1<=365)` and select **abmer** format. Press *OK*

[image]

**Step 5.** Enter formula for new rule `=AND($AO1="",$AM1<>"",TODAY()-$AM1<=330)` and select **green** format. Press *OK*

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: thanks simoco, thats just what I needed, works perfect

Answer (score 0):

UNtested but please try:

[image: SO21816833 example] where the individual rules in order as shown are:

- =NOT(ISBLANK(AO1)) (image does not match)
- =TODAY()-AM1>365
- =TODAY()-AM1>330
- =TODAY()-AM1<=330